# Raise all grouped windows on Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is there a way to raise all windows under the Windows 7 task-bar group

Example -

1. Open your preferred browser (don't
   maximise it)
2. Click the taskbar icon twice - it
   minimises and maximises (hide and
   raise)
3. Now open a second window for your
   browser (again don't maximise it -
   put it side by side with your other
   one)
4. Click the taskbar group-icon - you get a
   preview-list of windows, you need to choose
   one to hide or raise - just one at a time.

What I'm looking for is the ability to raise or hide all of them in the group.  So either:

- Click the browser taskbar group-icon, both windows raise, click it again - both lower; OR
- Click the browser taskbar group-icon, click the preview window in some way that indicates all of the windows in the group

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's something I've found that does what I need, not one click, but not too bad.

Hold down `ctrl` and click on a group - each time you do one of the windows will be restored in turn in its original position and brought to focus on top.  After sufficient clicks all windows in the group will be on top.

Clicking more times than there are windows is harmless as the windows remain on top, you only change which exact window has the focus.

I hope this is of some use to others.

Comment: It's the best of the not-great solutions.

Comment: The best of all TERRIBLE solutions, yes. If I have 4 explorer windows open, I need to not only hold a key down but ALSO click 4 times (!!!!) on my mouse to restore them all. And Windows is supposed to be for professionals. OMG.

Answer (score 4):

Shift+right-click to get options such as cascading the windows or stacking them. It won't restore their original positions, but it will get them all open on the screen.

[image]

Comment: Note that you have to right-click on an empty section on the taskbar to do this.

Comment: Incorrect. You can right-click on a program which has multiple windows open and get the same menu. It will then only apply that action to those windows. If you click on an empty section of the taskbar, it will apply the action to all your open windows.

Comment: -1 to Hello71 for incorrect information

Comment: Thanks for the info - The cascade or side-by-side options will be useful to some people, but not to my requirements.

What I'm after is essentially is "Restore All Windows", but bring them to the front also.  It seems that "Restore" will only be available if at least one of the windows have been minimised, and may restore them under other unrelated windows.

Comment: @nhinkle - Thanks also for getting me thinking about ctrl/shift/alt type modifiers.  I've found something that works thanks to your inspiration.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it to work!